# Program not resulting in deadlock

Tags: java

I am trying to achieve deadlock condition in this program
This program is not giving deadlock condition .Why?
Please tell me what is the problem in this code.

The output is :

> Thread1 : locked Integer
>   Thread2 : locked String
>   Thread1 : locked String
>   Thread2 : locked Integer

**Code:**

```
 class Dead {
    public void meth1() {
        synchronized (Integer.class) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: locked Integer");
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        synchronized (String.class) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: locked String");
        }
    }

    public void meth2() {
        synchronized (String.class) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: locked String");
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        synchronized (Integer.class) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: locked Integer");

        }
    }

}

class MThread1 extends Thread {
    Dead d;

    MThread1(Dead d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public void run() {
        d.meth1();
    }

}

class MThread2 extends Thread {

    Dead d;

    MThread2(Dead d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public void run() {
        d.meth2();
    }

}

public class Thread1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Dead d = new Dead();
        MThread1 t1 = new MThread1(new Dead());
        MThread2 t2 = new MThread2(new Dead());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
synchronized (Integer.class) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: locked Integer");
        }
```

it locks Integer.class object and immediately unlocks it.  You want this:

```
synchronized(Integer.class) {
    System.out.println("Thread 1: locked Integer");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    synchronized(String.class) {
        System.out.println("Thread 1: locked String");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect it to turn into deadlock? Try following code:

```
//in method meth1
synchronized(Integer.class) {
     //blah blah
     synchronized(String.class) {
          //blah blah
     }
}

//in method meth2
synchronized(String.class) {
     //blah blah
     synchronized(Integer.class) {
          //blah blah
     }
}
```

See the way lock is being obtained here, if you try running it multiple times, you will see the deadlock.

In your case, you just get a lock on class object (while other method waiting for it) and release the lock from one method and other takes it and hence no deadlock.

Deadlock will occur when `meth1` holds lock on `Integer.class` and waiting to hold lock on `String.class` while `meth2` will hold lock on `String.class` and waiting to hold lock on `Integer.class` which is held by `meth1`.